# How can I go to previous commits on github and write test and add them back to final project Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, rspec

I taught myself how to code and started building an app. I finished the app's basic structure but when I began I did NOT see the value in test. I didnt get it. Now I COMPLETELY see the value in test.

My question is how can I go back to early github commits and branch off of those and write test at that point in time and then add that test back into my main finished project? That way I can go slowly step-by-step vs. being overwhelmed with how many test I did not write.

Also, I can make sure I cover each area to test?

Any thoughts and how do I do this without screwing up even worse?!

-EDIT-
the reason I want to do it this way instead of just writing test is because when I try and use rspec I am getting errors on 3rd party gems. I want to write test before those gems were installed and figure out my issues from there. If that makes sense.

Comment: It sure is OK! To make sure you don't miss anything, use simplecov to tell you what code is covered by your tests.

Answer (score 1):

I would start by writing very basic tests first. And then slowly add tests for main features of your app. You should start writing test on your "develop" branch. You are doing the right thing and do not get intimidated by the amount of work. Slowly  and steadily you can achieve this goal.